# OpenCV PCA question

Tags: opencv, pca

I'm trying to create a PCA model in OpenCV to hold pixel coordinates. As an experiment I have two sets of pixel coordinates that maps out two approximate circles. Each set of coordiantes has 48 x,y pairs. I was experimenting with the following code which reads the coordinates from a file and stores them in a Mat structure. However, I don't think it is right and PCA in openCV seems very poorly covered on the Internet.

```
    Mat m(2, 48, CV_32FC2); // matrix with 2 rows of 48 cols of floats held in two channels

pFile = fopen("data.txt", "r");

for (int i=0; i<48; i++){
    int x, y;
    fscanf(pFile, "%d%c%c%d%c", &x, &c, &c, &y, &c);

    m.at<Vec2f>( 0 , i )[0] = (float)x; // store x in row 0, col i in channel 0
    m.at<Vec2f>( 0 , i )[1] = (float)y; // store y in row 0, col i in channel 1

}

for (int i=0; i<48; i++){
    int x, y;
    fscanf(pFile, "%d%c%c%d%c", &x, &c, &c, &y, &c);

    m.at<Vec2f>( 1 , i )[0] = (float)x; // store x in row 1, col i in channel 0
    m.at<Vec2f>( 1 , i )[1] = (float)y; // store y in row 1, col i in channel 1

}

PCA pca(m, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, 2); // 2 principle components??? Not sure what to put here e.g. is it 2 for two data sets or 48 for number of elements?

    for (int i=0; i<48; i++){
 float x = pca.mean.at<Vec2f>(i,0)[0]; //get average x
     float y = pca.mean.at<Vec2f>(i,0)[1]; //get average y
     printf("\n x=%f, y=%f", x, y);
}
```

However, this crashes when creating the pca object. I know this is a very basic question but I am a bit lost and was hoping that someone could get me started with pca in open cv.

Comment: Have you seen the [PCA section of OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#pca)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it would be helpful if you described in further detail what you need to use PCA for and what you hope to achieve (output?).

I am fairly sure that the reason your program crashes is because the input Mat is CV_32FC2, when it should be CV_32FC1. You need to reshape your data into 1 dimensional row vectors before using PCA, not knowing what you need I can't say how to reshape your data. (The common application with images is eigenFace which requires an image to be reshaped into a row vector). Additionally you will need to normalize your input data between 0 and 1.

As a further aside, usually you would choose to keep 1 less principal component than the number of input samples because the last principal component is simply orthogonal to the others.

I have worked with opencv PCA before and would like to help further. I would also refer you to this blog: http://www.bytefish.de/blog/pca_in_opencv  which helped me get started with PCA in openCV.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay in replying as I have been off sick with the flue!!! What I am trying to do is create a pca model for the mouth within images. What I do is sample points around the mouth in two images and want to create a pca model based upon my sample points. Therefore, in the first image, I have 48 (x,y) coordinates that follow the shape of the moth and in the second image I have another 48 points for a different mouth. I would then like to get the average mouth coordinates. I have been trying to find useful online resources but without luck.

Comment: I'll take a look at the blog you recommended as it looks useful. Any further hints and tips on how to create the desired model would be very much appreciated (if you or anyone else has the time)...

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks again for your help. I managed to get the code compiled by using CV_32FC1 and normalising the data as you said. It's funny the way a few hints from someone with more experience can save us a lot of heartache trying to find answers on Google. There is a number of good resources on PCA on the internet but very little   in the way of examples of PCA with OpenCV. So thanks a lot for your help, it was spot on!!!

Comment: No problem, can't agree more with what you said about a few examples making a huge difference.